# Validate minimum date JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to validate the minimum date (today) from an object type="date" for a CheckIn until the Checkout and then take the number of days to another variable for further use, all with a button. My problem is that I don't really understand how to compare the dates.

html

```
<label for="date1"> Checkin </label>
    <input type="date" id="date1">

<label for="date2"> Checkout </label>
    <input type="date" id="date2">

<button type="button" id="btn1" required>Action</button>
```

js

```
let btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
let checkIn = document.getElementById('date1');
btn1.addEventListener('click', minDate);

function minDate(){
    let nowDate = new Date;
    if(checkIn.value < Date){

        alert("invalid date")
    }

}
```

The function does alert if the date is lower than today but also shows the alert for any date after today.

Comment: Dates are generally difficult. I usually defer to a well tested library for many date related tasks. https://date-fns.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helo Christy.

In order to validate our date, we must first convert the inputs from the form into [javascript Date objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). We can do that, by passing the input into the constructor of the class. After that, we can simply compare the values.

```js
const btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
const checkIn = document.getElementById("date1");
btn1.addEventListener("click", minDate);

function minDate() {
  const checkInDate = new Date(checkIn.value);
  const nowDate = new Date();

  if (checkInDate > nowDate) {
    alert("Invalid date provided");
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="date1"> Checkin </label>
<input type="date" id="date1">

<label for="date2"> Checkout </label>
<input type="date" id="date2">

<button type="button" id="btn1" required>Action</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do that:

```
function minDate(){

    const nowDate = new Date();
    const valDate = new Date(checkIn.value)

    if(valDate < nowDate){

        alert("invalid date")
    }

}
```